MCU surge protection when controlling AC blinds motor using relay
I'm designing a very simple module to control blinds AC motor with MCU through relay:
(I tried bunch of various schematics,not sure which one so attach. Adding diagram instead)

When MCU enables the relay and motor starts AC current drops causing huge voltage spike up to 15-20V which gets through AC/DC power supply, and event LDO.
Here is what I tried so far and results:

Tried to search for solutions but surge protection always done on AC side. I need on DC side.
Add corresponding zeners before and after LDO (spikes still exist)
Add various capacitors close to LDO and MCU (spikes still exist)
Tired "voltage delay" circuit taken from: https://electronicsarea.com/surge-protection-circuit-voltage-delay-circuit/ (not providing enough power for MCU - it won't start)

Could anyone please suggest how to suppress spikes after AC/DC?
HiLink AC/DC (HLK-MP01) is a cheap PS from Aliexpress. Datasheet

The image is a block diagram, not a schematic.  It needs to be a schematic to provide the detail needed to help you.  Also links to the datasheets is helpful, eg: what is a "hi-link AC/DC"?

A DC supply delivering excessive output after mains transient, is malfunctioning outright. Suppression isn't the problem here, the supply is bad.

HiLink AC/DC (HLK-MP01) is a cheap PS from Aliexpress. Obviously it's not very high quality but it does it's work. It may lacks some stuff on DC part (due to small size)  to suppress spikes that why I'm asking what may be added?

"it does its work" -- but you have established it does not. Why then, defend it? Or, perhaps you have not followed the datasheet properly, for example I notice in the datasheet available from LCSC, an EMI circuit is recommended, have you tried that? We cannot tell -- this is why we ask for schematics, to have a firm footing to answer from.

Did you use a flyback diode across the relay coil?

Right... I mean after all it gives 5V@ 0.6A.  Yes I use flyback diode
